# Proxmox Mail Gateway - Relay access denied from Unknown Address

Tags: email-server, proxmox

Today I found a strange looking traffic in the Tracking Center

[image: pmg tracking center Entry]

Should I be alarmed by this or is this normal? to me it seems very strange.

Answer (score 0):

No, you needn't be alarmed by this. Why would it alarm you?

A mail server is exposed to the public internet. Therefore, unknown agents may connect to your mail server at any time.

Someone might try to use your mail server as a mail relay. If you have configured your mail server properly, they will fail.